# Reverse engineering google photos share cache

Tags: android, caching, photo

I'm trying to understand how and why a share-cache folder is created in: com.google.android.apps.photos/cache/share-cache/ as it contains one media.tmp file.

on android 12

I've tried a few things on a test handset and can't cause it to appear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.